# How would a teenager living in Bulgaria be able to monetize a website?

Tags: advertising

I would like to ask about some advice because I am having trouble with monetizing a website I recently made. I want to run ads on the website, I've left some whitespace for the ads, and also I want to be able to make a one time payment on the site. These will be the 2 income methods. However the problems arise because of 2 things: - I am under 18 - live in Bulgaria, so not the things that apply to usa don't work the same here, we are in the EU if that could be of help

I looked at Google Adsense, but I need to create a bank account, which isn't an impossibility, but the main problem is that it requires a confirmation of the address and them having to send a letter here would take around a month or two(as far as I know, they send you some activation code by mail to confirm your address, might be outdated information)

The website is this (it doesn't have any content yet, as it is not launched yet 'officially', just some random filler text for testing purposes): http://alfalife.herokuapp.com/

The niche is obviously fitness & health

Comment: You cannot apply for Adsense without a website. Google wants to review and approve the site. As well, if Google sees a website that is low quality or thin content, it will reject the application. It is far better to wait till you have a website that is mature enough to attract search users and offer a reasonable amount of content. Otherwise, one an application is rejected, it becomes harder to be approved through the review process - though not impossible. The same criteria applies. All site reviews are done by a human so make sure you have done a reasonable job. Cheers!!

Comment: Unless your website is getting thousands of visitors a day you won't make any money anyway.  Websites can typically make between $1 and $5 (USD) with advertising per 1000 visitors.    In addition what closetnoc says about creating your website before applying, it just isn't worth running ads for a couple pennies a day.   You have plenty of time to apply before your website is drawing the numbers of users it needs to be profitable for you.

Comment: "The niche is obviously fitness & health" look's like you've read too many nonsense guide about affliate marketing. There are too many opportunities other then fitness and health. If you like games, so start reviewing your favorite games and wait for some traffic, then tons of CPA ad network will contact you to promote their advertiser games. Create a site that you're passionate about it, there are all kind of advertiser out there to give you money for promotion.

Comment: I am from Slovakia, and I am using AdSense and the activation code came after 10 days of reaching 10$ (the amount when the activation code will be sent). Personally, I would go for AdSense if the website is starting.

Comment: I just wanted to correct Goyllo, I just mentioned that the website is about fitness and health, so that ad providers who are good for those types of websites would be recommended. I haven't done any reading (which I should about marketing and such, this is just a little project for me and my friends who constantly talk gyms, food etc :) )

Answer (score 1):

I would affiliate health niche products and use social media marketing to build a following. Blog, post on social media, engage people (you can automate this with tools eventually), and have a section on your site to buy products.

In my opinion, this is a more reasonable way to make money than a few pennies from adsense. Build up a mailing list, produce great content, find other collaborators in the niche and have fun with it. Ads are for big sites and bloggers who don't know how to make money.

My two cents.

Comment: "Ads are for big sites and blogger who don't know how to make money" really? Can you fight with honest review vs affliate product review? just search out on Google "Grammerly review" and you will see grammarist.com website, which posted real things about that, while other blogger just mention good thing to get higher CR. Big sites making tons of money with Google DFP and Ad Exchange. There are three kind of people making real money, first is Big sites, second is CPA marketer and third is blogger who mention affliate links. Adsense pay $1 per click, do affliate offers gives you $1 EPC?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your argument is but it doesn't seem helpful to the question-asker. 

You're example of grammarist is a website that ranks for 'grammerly review' so that's highly qualified traffic to promote an affiliate link to. I'm guessing the person who is just starting their website isn't close to ranking for something like that.

Comment: I am just correcting you that, adsense does not pay only pennies. Nothing personal cheers :)